# putting a variable inside a string, it's not working?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have a string stored in `session[:login]` that I want used in a SQL query, so I wrote this.

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['user = "#{session[:login]}"'])
```

why doesn't this work? Thanks!

Comment: Ruby's single quoted strings do not interpolate, double quoted strings do; SQL uses single quotes for string literals, double quotes are (usually) used for quoting identifiers.

Comment: hmm, interesting, thanks for the info

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can rebuild your query this way:

```
@users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ['user = ?', session[:login]])
```

But this one looks better:

```
@users = User.where(user: session[:login])
```

Comment: It's important to note here that you should almost **always** use the provided SQL escaping methods and *never* do it yourself as in the original question. +1 for doing it the right way.

Comment: As a note, `User.where(...).all` is equivalent to `User.find(:all, ...)` but is mostly similar without the `.all`.

Answer (score 4):

This is just a string without any variable interpolation: `'user = "#{session[:login]}"'`

A string with variable interpolation looks like this: `"user = '#{session[:login]}'"`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
 @users = User.find(:all, :conditions => ["user = '#{session[:login]}' "])
```

use double quotes externly and internly single quotes.